# why is $O(n^2)$ equal to $n^{1.5}$?

Tags: algorithms, big-o-notation

I am learning this MIT [course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/assignments/MIT6_006F11_ps1_sol.pdf), which gives this formula

$$O(n^2) = n^{1.5}$$

is there a table to calculate this? like $O(n^{1.5})$, $O(n^{5})$ ?

what x takes would have O(x) give $c \cdot n$  where c is a constant,

Comment: can you citate us teh definition of O? this will immediately give yiou an answer

Answer (score 3):

The formula is wrong. The notation $f = O(g)$ is asymmetric, and has the meaning $f \in O(g)$. For more, check our [reference question on Landau notation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use). Other relevant reference questions are [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth) and [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88577/what-does-the-big-o-complexity-of-a-function-mean).

Comment: Just saying: The website gets it right, the poster swapped the sides.